# Custom post type paging return home page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, pagination

I am having problem with Custom post type paging. Clicking on 2nd page of paging through back to home page. Permalinks flush/refreshed and i am using simple code to show custom post.

following is my code

```
$cpt_type =  get_the_title();
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$custom_terms = get_terms('types');
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => $cpt_type, 'paged' => $paged, 'order', 'desc'/*, 'tax_query' => array( array('taxonomy' => 'type', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $custom_term->slug ))*/);
$customPostQuery = new WP_Query($args);
if($customPostQuery->have_posts() ):
    while($customPostQuery->have_posts()) : $customPostQuery->the_post();
        global $post;

<h4>Terms: <?php $custom_term->name; ?></h4>
<h3 class ="cq-h3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
<p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>

endwhile;
    function cpt_pagination($pages = '', $range = 4){
        $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
        global $paged;
        if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
        if($pages == ''){
            global $wp_query;
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages){
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }
        if(1 != $pages){
            echo "<nav aria-label='Page navigation example'>  <ul class='pagination'> <span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
            if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
            if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";
            for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++){
                if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )){
                    echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class=\"page-item active\"><a class='page-link'>".$i."</a></li>":"<li class='page-item'> <a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"page-link\">".$i."</a></li>";
                }
            }
            if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo " <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">i class='flaticon flaticon-back'></i></a></li>";
            if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo " <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'><i class='flaticon flaticon-arrow'></i></a></li>";
            echo "</ul></nav>\n";
        }
    }
    if (function_exists("cpt_pagination")) {
        cpt_pagination($customPostQuery->max_num_pages);
    }
```

kindly correct me where i've placed wrong code.
my cpt is 'lectures'

Comment: Looks like you're re-implementing WordPress's archive functionality inside of page template, perhaps? Which template file is this in? This seems like [a X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). WordPress will return the home page when the product of the query arguments is an empty query - when the arguments conflict or don't make sense together to such an extent that WordPress removes one or more. In this case, that's probably happening because your pagination args are affecting the main query but you're using a secondary query for content.

Comment: its template-lectures.php

Comment: is there a reason you didn't use the standard post archive for the lectures post type combined with the dedicated template file ( `archive-lectures.php` ) and the `pre_get_posts` filter to adjust the parameters? Putting a `WP_Query` loop or equivalent at the top of a template doesn't override the main query, it just doubles the amount of work WP does and forces you to write a lot of code to undo new bugs it creates. e.g. what happens if the main query has 4 pages but yours has 5? WP uses the main query to figure that out